# Highcharts Bar Graphic: Make small number the higher bar and large number the smaller bar

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am making a simple column chart using Highcharts. The chart shows the ranking of Mexican states from 1 - 32. As one is first place and 32 the last, I would like to make it so the chart shows 1st place as the tallest column and 32nd place as the smallest column, but the tooltips still show the correct information (i.e. 1 still shows 1 and not 32). Make sense? Anyone have any suggestions on how to go about this? The code is below. Many thanks in advance!

```
<h2>Ranking 2019</h2>
<div class="ranking-graphic-wrapper">
<div id="container2019" style="width: 60vw; height: auto;">

<script>

        Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
    decimalPoint: ',',
    thousandsSep: '.'
  },
});

var chart = Highcharts.chart('container2019', {
       chart: {
            backgroundColor: '#f3f7fa',
                    type: 'column',
                    zoomType: 'xy'
            },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    exporting: {
         buttons: {
                  contextButton: {
                  align: 'right',
                  x: 0
                  }
             },
        chartOptions: {
               chart: {
                       events: {
                load: function() {
                this.renderer.image('http://165.22.82.145/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/IDDMEX-Logo.svg',
                505, // x
                500, // y
                    75, // width
                    40 // height
                 ).add();
                     }
                    }
            }
        }
 },
    plotOptions: {
    series: {
      zones: [
        {
          value: 8,
          color: "#B3CDE0",
        },
        {
          color: "#6497B1",
          value: 16
        },
        {
          color: "#005B96",
          value: 24
        },
        {
          color: "#03396C",
          value: 32
        }
      ],
      states: {
        inactive: {}
      }
    }
  },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ["Querétaro","San Luis Potosí", "Yucatán", "Sonora", "Coahuila", "Tabasco", "Hidalgo", "Zacatecas", "Campeche", "Guanajuato","Ciudad de México","Quintana Roo","Aguascalientes","Baja California Sur", "Oaxaca", "Puebla", "Chihuahua", "México", "Tlaxcala","Colima","Nayarit","Chiapas","Baja California", "Michoacán", "Durango", "Morelos", "Sinaloa", "Veracruz", "Nuevo León","Guerrero","Jalisco","Tamaulipas"]
    },

  yAxis: {
        max: 32,
    title: {
       text: 'Ranking'
       }
  },

    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        color:"#011F4B",
    name: 'Índice',
        data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32],
        showInLegend: false
    }]
});

</script>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some custom property to data point and show it in a tooltip:

```
tooltip: {
  pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">●</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.custom.realVal}</b><br/>'
},

series: [{
  data: [{
    y: 1,
    custom: {
      realVal: 32
    }
  }, {
    y: 2,
    custom: {
      realVal: 31
    }
  }, ...],
  ...
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4968/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data.custom

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat

Comment: Thank you ppotaczek. I think this will be part of the solution. Perhaps this photo will provide a better explanation of what I'm trying to achieve. https://online-file-storage.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/goal.png

Comment: Hi @Psychedelic Wizard, Thanks for the image! Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4973/